# Skip earlier implicit template parameter, but not later, in a template parameter list

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am just curious:

On the following sample I show what I mean in place of `/*implicit*/`.
Is there a workaround to leave it blank? typename T cannot be first as you can see.

```
template<typename C1, typename C2, typename T = decltype(typename C1::value_type() * typename C2::value_type())>
T dot(const C1 &v1, const C2 &v2);

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> vec1;
    std::vector<double> vec2;
    // typical:
    auto result1 = dot(vec1, vec2); // auto -> double
    // avoid numerical unstable situations:
    auto result2 = dot</*implicit*/,/*implicit*/,long double>(vec1, vec2); // auto -> long double
    //auto result2 = dot<decltype(vec1),decltype(vec2),long double>(vec1, vec2);
}
```

In the last line, I provide a solution witch is not super-bloated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reorder the parameters, and go conditional:

```
// short notation for `std::declval<typename C::value_type&>()`
template<class C>
typename C::value_type& value_in();

// if T == void, find actual result type, else use T
template<class T, class C1, class C2>
using DotResult = typename std::conditional<std::is_void<T>::value,
    decltype(value_in<C1>() * value_in<C2>()), T>::type;

// void can't be a valid value_type
template<class T = void, class C1, class C2>
DotResult<T,C1,C2> dot(C1 const& c1, C2 const& c2);
```

However, I have to admit... I really don't see the use for it - you could just cast the result instead, or implicitly convert it... `long double x = dot(v1, v2);`

Comment: I imagine that the type is not just used as the result, but might also be used internally for the operations. Operating on a `long double` will yield a different result than operating internally with `double` and then converting to `long double` (and viceversa: unconditionally using `long double` internally might be slower and yield a different result than using `double` for the case where the type is not fixed on the call)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Every floating point type converted from CPU to 10-byte floating point which is `long double`. This conversion usually is needless (defaulted) but in some cases (Finite Element Analysis) `T=float` can lead to numerical unstable situations. From the other side, promote vectors to `double` elements leads to super huge memory blocks.

Comment: @Chameleon: I don't see why that comment is directed at me. I was trying to tell Xeo (maybe I failed horribly?) that there are reasons to do calculations in a different size than the containers hold, as a comment to his last paragraph and in particular to *you could cast the result instead*

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yeap. You are right. It is directed to Xeo.