# Derive earlier template parameters when later parameter given

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

Given

```
template <typename S, typename T>
T make_T(S const &s) { ... }
```

How can I leave `S` to be derived while explicitly providing `T`?

I would like to be able to say:

```
auto t = make_T<auto, int>(S{});
```

but clang and gcc tell me that `auto` is not allowed in template argument.
Had the arguments happened to be reversed in the prototype of `make_T`,
then all would be well;
I could explicitly give `T` and leave `S` to be derived.

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199863/skip-earlier-implicit-template-parameter-but-not-later-in-a-template-parameter),
the proposed solution was to declare a helper function that reversed the arguments, e.g.,

```
template <typename T, typename S>
T make_T_reversed(S const &s) { return make_T<S,T>(s); }
```

which now enables

```
auto t = make_T_reversed<int>(S{});
```

as desired, but I'm hoping there might be a more direct way that doesn't require creating temporary helper functions. I'm asking as a new question because the accepted answer of the previous question doesn't answer my actual question:
*is* there a direct means of achieving this?
I'm feeling hopeful that with C++17 and C++20 (not around at the time of the previous question), there may now be, but I've sadly been unable to find it.

#### Further motivating examples

The use case initially motivating the question was that I wanted to write

```
std::unordered_set<T, default, default, Allocator> obj;
```

using the default values for the middle two template parameters
(`Hash` and `KeyEqual`),
but explicitly specifying the `Allocator` parameter.
I'm using the default constructor, so the type for `Allocator` cannot be derived.

I realise the question I actually asked isn't quite the same (I asked about deriving the values rather than taking the default values), but I'm hoping the same approach would work for both cases:

```
auto t = make_T<auto, int>(S{});
std::unordered_set<T, auto, auto, Allocator> obj;
```

Comment: You can define the helper inline: `auto t = []<typename T, typename S>(const S& s) { return make_T<S, T>(s); }.operator()<int>(s);` but that's still not direct

Comment: There's an elephant in the room: why is the template parameters in the wrong order to begin with?

Comment: I can't catch the problem. Why you need the "wrong order" of template parameters. Can you give a short real world example why you have such a problem?

Comment: @Artyer Thanks, I was wondering about that. It's not the solution I was looking/hoping for, but it's nevertheless nice to have in the arsenal, especially if there is no direct approach.

Comment: @PasserBy @Klaus Agreed, my example was a little contrived; clearly `make_T()` would have been far more sensibly defined with reversed arguments in the first place. I've added another motivating example, although I do realise it's different in nature to the `make_T()` case.

Answer (score 0):

if `S` is from `T` when `T` is provided, what you will provide for `S`?

`make_T<auto, int>()` is definitely impossible, but `make_T<void, int>()` may be acceptable for you?

```cpp
template<typename nS, typename T, typename S = std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<void, nS>, T, nS>>
T make_T(S const&);
```

but `S` is always deduced by the argument, why do you want `S` to be the first parameter?

or you want `S` to be determined?

```cpp
template<typename nS, typename T>
T make_T(std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<void, nS>, T, nS> const&);
```

Comment: Many thanks, although very much hoping for an approach that doesn't require modifying the original `make_T()` specification. I added another motivating example to the question.

Comment: @sircolinton I have to point out again: `auto` or `default` is not allowed as a template argument, you must provide a type. for the common use, we provide `void` (or some special type tag, like `std::monostate`) when we want a default argument. and actually it's impossible to provide `Allocator` argument but want `Hash` and `KeyEqual` to be still default argument, you must explicitly provide them as well.

Comment: I hope you clearly explain where and how `make_T` will be used, I think you may be stuck in an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). and as a standard practice of function template, you should put the template parameter that will be provided to the front, and one that will be deduced to the latter, and lastly use default template argument to do some type inference. you should consider why the template parameters will be in this order, and sometimes reorder them if necessary.

Comment: "for the common use, we provide `void` when we want a default argument": think we're talking cross-purposes here; calling `make_T<void, T>(...)` explicitly sets the template type `S` to being the concrete type `void`, rather than being a placeholder to tell the compiler to engage deduction or otherwise to figure out the type of `S`.

Comment: @sircolinton `void` always can not be an expected template argument. if necessary, you can declare a type tag `struct Placeholder` and use it instead of `void`. in this case, `Placeholder` should never be used as a normal type.

Comment: Very sure we're talking at least partly cross-purposes. I recognise that `make_T<auto, T>(...)` is not valid C++ syntax, but suppose for a moment it were; what would you expect that syntax to mean? Seems very clear that it means "I'm explicitly setting the second template parameter, but oh glorious compiler, go forth and figure out a suitable value for the first (e.g., using type deduction or using a default value if one was given in `make_T`'s specification). My question is: is such a thing possible with current C++?

Comment: @sircolinton 1. `auto` or `default` is invalid, at least now. 2. you can use `void` or `struct Placeholder` to do as which you want `auto` to do. what else do you want? EXACTLY `auto` for a template argument? the answer is NO.